# Copy data from a Google Sheet to another Google Sheet (not formatting or formulas)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to use this in Apps Script (I want to copy data form SHEET1 to SHEET2):

```
 function runsies() {
 importRange(
  "SOURCE_ID",
  "Sheet1!B2:E",
  "DESTINATION_ID",
  "Sheet2!B2"
 );
}

 function importRange(sourceID, sourceRange, destinationID, destinationRangeStart) {
  const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID);
  const sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange);
  const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();

  const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID);
  const destStartRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationRangeStart);
  const destSheet = destinationSS.getSheetByName(destStartRange.getSheet().getName());

  destSheet.clear();

  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(
    destStartRange.getRow(),
    destStartRange.getColumn(),
    sourceVals.length,
    sourceVals[0].length
  );
  destRange.setValues(sourceVals);

 }
```

From some reason it's not working, I dont have the date in the Destionation Sheet. Both Sheets are in the same SpreedSheet.

I need to mention that data form SHEET1 are there from another SHEET and I use

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE to bring them

I need only to get the data from SHEET1 to SHEET2 without the formulas.

Need some help please

Comment: You're missing the part of the code where you copy the data from the source range to the destination range. You've correctly fetched the data from 'SHEET1' (**STEP 1**), but you need to paste it into 'SHEET2' (**STEP 2**). It is not that your code is not working, it is just missing Step 2. Please have a look at: `.setValues`

Comment: Also, where do you want to copy it to:  a set range or do you want to append new rows in the destination sheet?

Comment: It helps to share a sample spreadsheet or a screenshot of your expected results so folks trying to help are not guessing at your requirements.

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a dummy sheet, that demonstrates the issue you're facing along with your desired result. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function copyDataFromOneGoogleSpreadsheetToAnother() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.test1id)
  const incl = ["Sheet0", "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4"];
  const arr = [];
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => ~incl.indexOf(sh.getName())).forEach(sh => {
    let vs = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    let dsh = dss.getSheetByName(sh.getName());
    dsh.clear();
    dsh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  });
}
```